# Sending Apple Push Notification from MVC Web Project

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-mvc, moonapns

I am not able to send Notifications to Apple Devices using the Moon-APNS. I have the APNS implementation in a separate Class Library Project as `MyProjet.APNS`. While adding reference of the class library `MyProject.APNS` to my Web Project `MyProject.Web`, the reference shows a yellow exclamation mark.

How do I make it run? Need help!

Comment: What is your target .NET framework for your Web solution? .NET 4? 4.5?

Comment: Solved it. The `MyProject.APNS` had the target .NET Framework set to 4.5.1 and `MyProject.Web` was set to 4.5

Comment: Thought it might be that. It's caught me out many times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your target .NET framework for your Web solution? .NET 4? 4.5?

Try checking it's compatible with your APNS project target framework.